# how to get multiple docs from firestore using its doc id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how do I get multiple docs from firestore using its doc id? which variable should I use?

```
await FS.collection(CollectionName.product)
                    .where("id", "in", productIDs)
                    .get()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the ID of a document as a field in a filter, you can use [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid).

```
FS.collection(CollectionName.product)
    .where(FS.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", productIDs)
    .get()
```

Your syntax might be different based on how you imported and initialized the SDK.

Comment: Cannot read property 'documentId' of undefined i got this.

Comment: using javascript

Comment: I know you're using JavaScript.  You need to figure out what the `firebase` part is, based on how you imported or required the firestore library and initialized firestore.   It's possibly just `FS`.